# How to count value group by date and row value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to count the evaluation score each month. The evaluation is ranging from 1-5. I want to show them in the table how many score of each evaluation is rated each month. This is the data. The date column is in this format : YYYY-MM-DD.

```
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
| date/eval | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|2015-06-01 | 10| 15| 2 | 3 | 0 |
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|2015-06-02 | 20| 11| 5 | 4 | 1 |
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|2015-06-03 | 5 | 10| 5 | 6 | 2 |
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
.
.
.
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|2015-06-30 | 10| 15| 2 | 3 | 0 |
+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Then I need to display the data in a table like this.

```
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| date/eval  | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|june 2015   |110|105| 32| 23| 0 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|july 2015   |132| 50| 21| 13| 0 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|august 2015 |151| 55| 42| 30| 0 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

All the sql script I can think about is `group by`. But it's only works for group by date.

Here's the script:

`select * from evaluation group by year,month(datetime) asc`

How to count the unique value of each evaluation.

Comment: please post structure of table `evaluation`

Comment: What's `year`? Is it another column on your table? Or will it be derived from the `date` column?

Comment: please see the update, I just edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create data structure and fill with test data:

```
CREATE TABLE evaluation (
  evaldate date NOT NULL,
  grade1 int(11) NOT NULL,
  grade2 int(11) NOT NULL,
  grade3 int(11) NOT NULL,
  grade4 int(11) NOT NULL,
  grade5 int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (evaldate)
);

INSERT INTO evaluation VALUES('2015-07-14', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO evaluation VALUES('2015-07-15', 2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO evaluation VALUES('2015-08-12', 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO evaluation VALUES('2015-08-13', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Perform the query you want to do:

```
SELECT year(evaldate)
     , month(evaldate)
     , sum(grade1)
     , sum(grade2)
     , sum(grade3)
     , sum(grade4)
     , sum(grade5) 
  FROM evaluation 
 group 
    by year(evaldate)
     , month(evaldate);
```

Returns:

```
year(evaldate) month(evaldate) sum(grade1) sum(grade2) sum(grade3) sum(grade4) sum(grade5)
2015           7               3           4           5           6           7
2015           8               6           5           4           3           2
```

This seems to me like the result you were looking for, right?

Comment: Far too generous an answer.